# ffmpeg hevc_toolbox producing video files with audio but no video

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a React Native application that is attempting to transcode users videos so they are in a format both platforms can natively playback, we are doing it on device for now as we don't want to incur the API costs till we have a stable user base.

I have a few questions and let me preface them with my ffmpeg knowledge is not the best and mostly cobbled together.

1. Why does the following code produce videos that are unplayable but still have audio.

   ```typescript
   if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
         await FFmpegKit.execute(`-i ${path} -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -y ${outputPath}`);
   } else {
         await FFmpegKit.execute(`-i ${path} -c:v hevc_omx -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -y ${outputPath}`);
   }
   ```
2. Is there a better set of commands to run for 1080p videos that will be played back on both platforms?

I am getting ffmpeg into the app using https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit and am using the `min-gpl` distribution. If I set the commands to use their h264 alternatives for the codec (`h264_videotoolbox` & `h264_omx`) it produces working files but I was hoping to use hevc to minimize the file sizes.

### Update - Solved

The `-tag:v hvc1` needed to be added so that Apple players can play the HEVC content.

Comment: Try adding `-tag:v hvc1`. Try playing the video using a different video player on different platform maybe (try using VLC player). Try `libx265` instead of `hevc_videotoolbox`. For better compatibility, try adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. Note that as long as the encoder is compatible with H.265, the video is supposed to be decoded with any H.265 decoder (assuming the decoder supports the profile and level). What is the type of the output file, is it MP4?

Comment: @Rotem I tried playing it with Quicktime and iOS default players both returned errors but played sound. I will try to add the tag and format. And yes the output is an mp4.

Comment: @Rotem thanks!! It was the tag flag. Lifesaver!